# drag scrolling jquery for touch screen

Tags: jquery, scroll, drag

I am searching for a jquery plugin for scroll in touch screens (mobile and not mobile)

I will use in every touch screen, mobile and desktop

wait for suggestions

Comment: I respond to my : http://the-taylors.org/jquery.kinetic/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery Kinetic is perfect for this
http://the-taylors.org/jquery.kinetic/